# Why my image is not following the cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I want my image to follow the cursor but the code I am using does not work. I can't figure out the problem here.

Code Preview:

```js
function followIt(e){

    var img=document.getElementById("img");

    img.style.left = e.clientX;
    img.style.top = e.clientY;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<style>
    #img{
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #000000;
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>

<body id="demo_body" onmousemove="followIt(event)">
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/g02SqdrF/followmouse.png" id="img">
</body>

<script src="script.js" text="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Tip: Don't use inline JS `on*` attributes - same as you hopefully don't use inline `style` attributes. Script and Style should be in one place only, and that's their respective tags or files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use CSS `position: fixed;` for your image, since `clientX/Y` are relative from the **viewport**
- Use the missing `"px"` in JS
- Use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline `on*` handlers
- Don't query the DOM inside expensive loops, cache your element once inside a variable and than use its variable reference inside your function

```js
const EL_img = document.querySelector("#img");

function followIt(e) {
  EL_img.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
  EL_img.style.top  = e.clientY + "px";
  // Or also:
  // EL_img.style.cssText = `left: ${e.clientX}px; top: ${e.clientY}px;`;
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove", followIt);
```

```css
#img{
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #000000;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g02SqdrF/followmouse.png" >
```

Comment: @mplungjan if you remember, clientX and clientY are always relative units **from the viewport** - which for `position: fixed` is the best. you could do - since it also relates to the viewport.

Comment: @verna fixed a smaller typo. You're welcome.